# Ranking data frame

Tags: r

Her is my data:

```
x<- data.frame(P=c("M","C","M","C","C","M","C","M"),
    Q=c(13,12,12,14,19,15,12,11),
    R=c(15,13,21,32,32,21,13,32),
    T=c(15,12,12,14,12,11,19,15))
```

I want to calculate means for variables within each category.
For example means for  Q is:  M= (13+12+15+11)= 12.75 and for C= (12+14+19+12)= 14.25 and so on.

Next, I want to rank the means for each variable and get the following table:

```
P   Q   R   T
M   2   2   2
C   1   1   1
```

I want to get equal rank for my real data.
For example. if I have three 12, all will get the same rank

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
aggregate(.~P, x, mean)
```

Or

```
library(dplyr)
x1 <-   x %>%
          group_by(P) %>%
           summarise_each(funs(mean)) 
x1
# P     Q     R     T
#1 C 14.25 22.50 14.25
#2 M 12.75 22.25 13.25
```

For ranking

```
x1 %>%
    mutate_each(funs(rank(-.)), Q:T)
#  P Q R T
#1 C 1 1 1
#2 M 2 2 2
```

#### Update

Suppose if there are ties,

```
 x1$Q[2] <- x1$Q[1]
```

`rank` will get the ties averaged by default.  You can specify the `ties.method` to `min` or use `min_rank`

```
  x1 %>% 
     mutate_each(funs(min_rank(-.)), Q:T)
  #  P Q R T
  #1 C 1 1 1
  #2 M 1 2 2
```

Comment: @USER2313456  My solution was based on your example dataset.  It gives the expected result as you showed.  If your data is different, please do update it in your post.

Comment: @USER2313456  Also, depending on the ties in the mean values, you may need to check `?dense_rank` or `?min_rank` etc.

Comment: Do you know how I can add the ranks as separate columns and not overwrite existing ones? i.e., how can I supply names to `mutate_each`.. any ideas? Gave up after a while...

Comment: @Arun With `mutate_each` it may not be possible.  One option would be to use `bind_cols` with the original dataset, which may not be that elegant.

Comment: Okay, that explains my struggle then.. thanks. It seems to name columns automatically if we've more than one function though.

Comment: @Arun It would have been great to have the option to keep the original columns as well.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, here's a possible `data.table` solution using `frank` from the [devel version on GitHub](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

For means

```
library(data.table) ## v >= 1.9.5
(Res <- setDT(x)[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = P])
#    P     Q     R     T
# 1: M 12.75 22.25 13.25
# 2: C 14.25 22.50 14.25
```

For ranks

```
Res[, 2:4 := lapply(-.SD, frank, ties.method = "dense"), .SDcols = 2:4]
Res
#    P Q R T
# 1: M 2 2 2
# 2: C 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

to get the mean you can do this

```
do.call(rbind,lapply(split(x, f = x$P), function(x) data.frame(P = unique(x$P), Q = mean(x$Q), R = mean(x$R), T = mean(x$T))))
```

Comment: I think `do.call(rbind,lapply(split(x, f=x$P), function(x) c(P=x[1,1],colMeans(x[-1])) ))` would be a bit more compact (not tested though)